# Converting mp4 files and copying through directories

Tags: macos, video, ffmpeg

I needed a script to take full-size videos recorded on my camera, recompress them, create a compressed version, and then move the original to another folder after it was converted. I then import the compressed files into Lightroom rather than the originals. It works well, except I wish it only move the original file if the compressed copy was successfully created. Ideas for improving this script are welcome! I am using Mac OS X.

```
#Convert everything in the subdirectories of a directory called "Unprocessed", storing the converted file in the "Processed/Converted" directory, fixing the 420p issue if the file is an AVI files, then move the original to a corresponding subdirectory of "Processed/Completed" for i in Unprocessed/*/*/*.*; 
do o=$i; 
    echo Target is $o; 
    filename=`echo ${o##*/}`;
    echo Filename is $filename;
    tree=`echo $o | cut -d'/' -f2-3`; 
    echo Tree is $tree;
    echo Directory to create is "Processed/Converted/$tree";
    mkdir -p "Processed/Converted/$tree";
    base=`echo ${filename%.*}`;
    echo Base is $base;
    newfile="Processed/Converted/$tree/$base.mp4";
    echo Newfile is $newfile; 
    ffmpeg -i "$i" -map_metadata 0 -pix_fmt yuv420p "${newfile}"; 
    echo Destination to move to is "Processed/Completed/$tree";
    mkdir -p "Processed/Completed/$tree";
    mv "$i" "Processed/Completed/$tree"; 
done;
```

Comment: What OS? Also, it's a good idea to include the software you prefer to use in the tags.

Comment: Mac OS. I also added some tags. (Sorry, first time doing this.)

Comment: See shellcheck.net first.